# BrowserSync proxy not rewriting host in URLs

Tags: homestead, browser-sync

I am using the BrowserSync proxy to proxy to a Laravel Homestead instance.

I originally used the hostname as the target but my DNS had issues resolving it so I changed it to the following:

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: {
        target: "192.168.10.10",
        reqHeaders: function (config) {
            return {
                "host": "example.dev",
            }
        },
    }
});
```

The issue is that any URLs in the response are still the original, e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.dev/builds/css/main.css" />
```

I would assume this should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/builds/css/main.css" />
```

Anyone know why this happening or whether this may be a bug?